# Azure Web App wwwroot not updated after successful Azure devops deployment

Tags: laravel, azure, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

struggling to understand, what is wrong with my WebApp or deployment configuration. I'm using Azure devops pipeline to build and deploy my webapp (frontend Angular, backend Laravel). 
Deployment pipeline seems to work (not getting any errors) but wwwroot folder is not updated with latest files. I have tried to search different logs, but not success yet.

Here's my release config:
[Release pipeline config screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoHrq.jpg)

I have made one new file and small update in other file, I can see correct log when release gets executed. (Added test.blade.php and updated welcome.blade.php file).
Here's the release/deployment log:
[Release pipeline Azure App Service Deploy logs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8ZH5.jpg)

From the logs everything seems correct, but when looking app/site and files with Kudu, then I can't see those updates. At the same time, deleting all files and running release again, files get uploaded to wwwroot.

I have been struggling with it now few days, appreciate any help or guidance, what I could additionally check or change.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to update, no luck with WebApp deployment, switched to FTP upload (also part of the DevOps pipeline). Case closed.